# Show previously review-banned users in Review Ban List

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review, moderator-tools, review-suspension

There's a link from the Mod Links section where [Mods can ban users from reviewing](/admin/review/bans). There's also a section which shows *currently* banned users.

Unfortunately, currently there's no place which lists *previously* review banned users. Can we have this just below the Currently Banned Users list? Preferably, with the number of times they've been banned(not mandatory, since we can get this piece from user history)

The intention is simple, at least on SU, we'd like to follow up on users who've been review banned previously to see if there's been any change in the pattern. While doing a check on a user who I was about to review ban, I had no idea that the user was review banned 5 times before, till slhck told me of it (via user history). Having a list makes for easy lookup on the users' review ban history

Comment: Rather than having three lists and manually cross referencing, wouldn't it be better to request an indicator on the potential ban subjects that shows whether or not they've been previously banned? Realize I am just guessing here as I have no idea what info is displayed on that screen.

Comment: @BinaryTox1n that ban list is to ban a user from *all* review lists - not a specific one

Comment: Link broken **->** [Mods can ban users from reviewing.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/admin/review/bans)

Comment: @RumitPatel it's broken only if you dont have the necessary privileges.

Comment: Okay @Sathya. got it.

Answer (score 20):

**Update: August 30, 2017**

The latest build has added a new tab to the Review Ban page available to moderators to see a historical list of users who have been review banned. It includes user name, and the total number of times they have been banned. This information isn't really new because you could see it on each individual profile page, but we've put it all in a single location.

---

While we do display the total number of times a user has been banned on their profile, we don't give a full list of these bans anywhere. I also think this would be a good idea to get into place.

I've gone ahead and added it to the [backlog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291031/what-features-did-the-community-team-discuss-have-implemented-or-have-denied-l) of things for the team to discuss and possibly send to the dev team.  I'll add the [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) tag while it's going through the process.

Comment: I respect you adding more feature requests to that list, but with [163 such requests there already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-deferred) don't you think it's better to first, well, treat those that were added in the past? Or at least remove them from the list and remove the tag? It just builds false hopes. I mean, take [this for example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251267/give-diamond-moderators-back-the-ability-to-merge-users). One of the recent, compared to others. Over two years, not a single response to comments asking about progress.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yup, and I believe the plan is to do that. All of these that I've touched today had a status-review on them (placed by me), but I've now written them up for discussion so the deferred works, until we decide to do it or decline it.