# Failed review ban - 30 day window - clarification please

Tags: support, review, review-audits, post-ban

I found an explanation of the duration of the review bans after failed audits in the answer to this question [The time of automatic review bans should be increased with every new ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174118/the-time-of-automatic-review-bans-should-be-increased-with-every-new-ban/190562#190562)

```
each review ban counts (even manual ones made by moderators).
a 30 day window is used
1st ban within the window -> duration: 2 days
2nd ban within the window -> duration: 7 days 
3rd ban within the window -> duration: 30 days
```

Can I get more detailed explanation of how the "30 day window" works? Is it a set window (more or less monthly)? Or is it a rolling window from the first failed audit? Does failing another audit restarts the window?

Or is it knowledge that should not be made public?

Comment: As I understand it - in the last 30 days, but I'm not sure.

Comment: 2 days from the first failed review audit? Ehhm, do we invalidate all reviews that happend in that time? Would that invalidate the failed reviews too? Would that create a paradoxon?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn [Do not question the all powerful Stack Exchange leaders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandfather_paradox).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the comments under the answer you linked, I am interpreting that to mean that it is a rolling 30-day window, which is what I think makes the most sense anyways in terms of scheduling (I'm not a fan of the fact that you are [completely off the hook](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174118/the-time-of-automatic-review-bans-should-be-increased-with-every-new-ban/190562#comment591021_190562) after 30 days without having to demonstrate that you learned from the 30-day ban, but that's probably a separate argument).

To illustrate it better, here is a hypothetical timeline<sup>1</sup>

- First audit is failed on 10/7
- First ban is 2 days and you are unbanned on 10/9
- Second audit is failed on 10/11
- Second ban is 7 days since you failed 2 audits in the last 30 days and you are unbanned on 10/18
- Third audit is failed on 10/25
- Third ban is 30 days since you failed 3 audits in the last 30 days and you are unbanned on 11/24
- Fourth audit is failed on 11/28
- Since you have not failed any audits within the last 30 days, the 4th ban is 2 days again.

And here is an alternate timeline

- First audit is failed on 10/7
- First ban is 2 days and you are unbanned on 10/9
- Second audit is failed on 10/25
- Second ban is 7 days since you failed 2 audits in the last 30 days and you are unbanned on 11/1
- Third audit is failed on 11/9
- Third ban is 7 days again since you have failed only 2 audits in the last 30 days -

<sup>1 - dates are in MM/DD format</sup>

Comment: [You can fail an audit without getting banned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work).