# Questions closed as duplicate include references to those that do not answer the question

Tags: bug, flags, duplicate-questions, close-reasons, declined-flags

As an example, consider the following question:

> [Review Audit shows an answer that's duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203370/review-audit-shows-an-answer-thats-duplicate)

I flagged it (*incorrectly*) as a duplicate of [Review-beta: Obviously good answer in low-quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142998/review-beta-obviously-good-answer-in-low-quality) and the flag was **declined**.  Somebody [commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203370/review-audit-shows-an-answer-thats-duplicate#comment648116_203370) as well, saying: `@devnull no it's not a duplicate. The audit is misleading not a "good answer in low-quality"`.

Great!  But the question was eventually closed as a duplicate.  It reads:

> **This question already has an answer here:**
>
> [Review-beta: Obviously good answer in low-quality](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142998/review-beta-obviously-good-answer-in-low-quality)
>   1 answer
>
> ['Good' review audits can be misleading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195103/good-review-audits-can-be-misleading)
>   1 answer

Isn't it incorrect that the question be marked as a duplicate of the first one given that the flag was incorrect and had been declined?

---

EDIT: The comments ([this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204411/questions-closed-as-duplicate-include-references-to-those-that-do-not-answer-the#comment653037_204411) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204411/questions-closed-as-duplicate-include-references-to-those-that-do-not-answer-the#comment653045_204411)) attribute the *behavior* to the "herd-effect".  Is there a way to remove the incorrect question from the list of duplicates?  Should I flag it for moderator attention for removing the question incorrectly referred to as one of those having an answer?

Comment: What bug are you reporting here? 1) Question closed as a duplicate incorrectly or 2) Flag was declined but the question is closed for the same reason?

Comment: Not a bug but rather "herd effect" - your flag caused that question to appear as default when choosing to close and at least one user with more than 3K fell for this.

Comment: @hims056 The fact that the flag was incorrect and was declined but the question lists the incorrect one as that having an answer to the one that was closed.

Comment: @devnull - See the case #2 on [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105395/187824)

Comment: @hims056 So is it the same as what has been described as "herd effect" by ShaWizDowArd?

Comment: @devnull - Yes it is.

Comment: FWIW, general existence of herd effect seems to be proven experimentally, see [Bandwagon effect in close votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144557/bandwagon-effect-in-close-votes)

Comment: @gnat eh, nice find... totally forgot about that one! (would have linked otherwise :))

Comment: Regarding your edit, yes: if one of the dupes is really wrong then flag the question, choose "Other" and in there explain. Moderator can then re-open and close again quickly with the single proper target.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks.  Flagged as per your suggestion.