# Just failed my first review audit: Tried to flag an answer as a duplicate

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

So I just got review privileges, and I was given this answer to review: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20378044/2963903 (https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/3696530)

It was listed as two hours old, with no user. I opened the question, saw the answer from Chris, saw the wrong timestamp, and did not see the two-hour-old version. I thought that it was a copied answer (timestamps! you've failed me again), and concluded that "First Answers" might be hidden until it was approved in review. So I clicked "flag".

Maybe add some text saying, "Note: this answer is already up" (not in those words, obviously), or rather, have the text in the Queues page. (I already know just one audit failure won't count against me.)

Others who failed this:

- [Review Audit shows an answer that's duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203370/review-audit-shows-an-answer-thats-duplicate)
- ['Good' review audits can be misleading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195103/good-review-audits-can-be-misleading)

Comment: But...if we give away extra information that might indicate there is something special with the first-post wouldn't that defeat the whole purpose of audits?

Comment: Don't worry about it, it should be fine. Anyway, just remember that if you don't see two answers that are the same on the question page itself and there's a discrepancy in at least one of the statistics (e.g. votes), it's probably an audit.

Comment: That's why I said it'd be better to have the note in front. @Qantas94Heavy Well, _I_ know that now.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry. Some time ago I posted a similar question on meta in response to my failing a review audit. This one: [I failed a close queue review audit on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212314/i-failed-a-close-queue-review-audit-on-so)

The audit process is not perfect. I can attest from personal experience that there must be some tolerances built into any review banning algorithms that compensate for the audits only being reasonably accurate. Quite what they are, we'll never know as I doubt the SE team would ever be keen to release the finer details.

Comment: I'm wondering if there should or could be more community input in deciding what should be review audits. Perhaps something where it randomly chooses a review and has people vote it up or down. But my question is about failing a review audit because of not understanding how the process works, rather than because of a bad audit.

Comment: @leewangzhong in a way there is already community input.  Audits are selected based on criteria like up & down votes, flags, close votes, which are all generated by the community.  More often than note, the audits are good and there are too many audits needed to rely on any kind of manual process to select them.

Comment: Yes, they're selected by the community, as _good/bad answers_. Not selected as _clearly_ good or bad answers. But my question isn't about the audit questions chosen anyway.