# Some questions on how the review algorithms work exactly

Tags: support, review, review-audits, review-abuse, review-suspension

I would like to know how the review algorithm 'decides' that a late post need to be reviewed.

When a user fails a review audit, he gets this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKYEP.png]

If the same user failed too many review audits, he gets this:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xj5X3.png]

I would like to know the part of the algorithm that 'decides' the duration of the review suspension.

How does the algorithm decide that a user needs to be banned (definitively) from the review queues?

Comment: The duration part of your question is answered here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174118/the-time-of-automatic-review-bans-should-be-increased-with-every-new-ban

Comment: @TsSkTo : So, What about the actual duration of the 4rd and next suspensions?

Comment: The window used is thirty days. Meaning that if you get banned for thirty days(3rd ban) you will move into the next thirty day window. And start all over. So a fourth ban is impossible These bans are only in place to stop robo viewers and the like. If youre not trying to game the site to get the badges, you shouldnt worry too much about these audits

Comment: @TsSkTo : So, It mean if someone make two many mistake a 4rd time, he/she'll get suspended for 30 days again?

Comment: Just an odd question; Would it not be better to concern yourself with how to *avoid* being banned in the first place, instead of wondering how long each ban would be?

Comment: As I understand it, no. The bans are only counted in the thirty day window. So new window means a fresh set of bans. Meaning that your fourth ban should only be 2 days as it is considered a fisrst ban for the new period. Heres some more stuff on audits http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work

Comment: @AndrewBarber : Well, this is the difference between wanted vandalism and involuntary made mistakes... Please also note I took a picture from an another user ban.

Comment: Is there some reason you just deleted and reposted that comment?

Comment: @AndrewBarber : I've done some spell-checks