# Is it OK to delete/repost comments just for spell checking purposes?

Tags: discussion, comments

Comments can be edited during five minutes. After this delay, it can still be deleted. After the deletion, it is possible to repost the deleted comment with just spell-checks.

Is doing this OK?

Comment: I'm asking this because I [often do this kind of thing myself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208902/242800)

Comment: If you want to edit a post after 5 minutes delete and repost is the way. This only becomes a problem if someone has already @replied

Comment: @RichardTingle : Remember using comments for giving a full answer is not really OK. :)

Comment: Posting answers in comments is perfectly fine, so long as you don't expect them to be permanent.

Comment: The comment you reposted was over a day old, not at all hard to understand, and you "pinged" me again with you repost. No biggie... but neither was fixing it.

Comment: Didn't really feel substantial enough to be a real answer and I'm on mobile so I'm nt really in a position to be writing fulll answers

Comment: @richard I'd post a link to a near epic answer I once posted from mobile - including quotes and code - but I'm on mobile now.

Comment: I often posts answers as comments, if the question does not "deserve" a several line long answer. (Like `You need to do put a semicolon in the second line, this should fix it`) or [Add the shebang line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193825/running-tcl-file-from-terminal#comment30106717_20193825)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If a comment needs to be edited after the 5 minute window for whatever reason then deleting and reposting is the correct way to do this.

The only issue with this is if your existing comment has already been replied to; in which case you must balance the positive of correcting your comments to the negative of breaking the reply chain. If the reply chain is still relevant then it is best to leave the comment as is, if it is not then the entire chain should be deleted rather than corrected (you can flag the other side of the conversation as obsolete if this is the case).

Comment: for the sake of completeness, an obscure option is to flag for moderator asking them to do the correction (mods can edit comments) - but one would better have a _damn_ good reason for such a request (in more than 2 years at multiple SE sites, I did that 2 or maybe 3 times)

Comment: @gnat Yup; The only time I've ever done that sort of edit myself is in the case of an *extremely* useful (and still relevant/current) comment which just has some major issue.

Comment: @gnat Unlike questions or answers, normal user can't say why they flagged a comment. You can just click on the flag and answer to the confirmation. So, it is impossible to tell there are spell checks needs.

Comment: @user2284570 Comment flags have an "other" too