# How long does a ban or suspension on an SE site last?

Tags: support, account-suspension

I've tried to make some searches about ban and suspension but the data I found doesn't seem to correspond to my experience. I also cannot find a FAQ on the help section.

Can you explain me how these mechanics work?

I've just found [the feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174118/the-time-of-automatic-review-bans-should-be-increased-with-every-new-ban) for a review ban duration to be extended automatically at every new suspension [in an exponential way](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=exponential%20fit%202,%207,%2030,%20365). But it's speaking of 2, 7, 30 days.

I've heard from a moderator that the suspension duration is 7, 30, 365 days. Is that correct? Can a moderator change the duration of a suspension?

Comment: There are many types of bans. The one you linked to is about **review** ban but looks like you mean **post ban** which can last forever.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: thanks. Also for post ban the time is going to raise automatically after each ban? Which are the steps?

Comment: A post ban does not last for a certain amount of time. If you're banned, you're banned. Once you get out, you can get banned again. Time is not a factor here—only the quality of your posts. Theoretically, you could get banned and unbanned several times per day.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A ***timed suspension*** is a timed restriction of activities on a site. The date when it concludes is shown on the user profile page of the suspended user. Moderators can choose the length of suspensions at their discretion, but usually the first suspension will last 7 days, the second 30 days, and the third 365 days.

More information:

- [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)
- [My account has been temporarily suspended; what does that mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125268/)

A ***post ban*** (question ban or answer ban) is algorithmically determined, and lasts as long as there is poor content associated with the account. The only way to get yourself out of a post ban is to improve your existing content. It's also been suggested that posting good, well-received *answers* will help get you out of a *question* ban, and vice versa. The details of the algorithm are known only to the Stack Exchange team.

More information:

- [Help Center: Question bans](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)
- [Help Center: Answer bans](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answer-bans)
- [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

A ***review ban*** is a timed suspension from one or more review queues. It can be triggered by failing too many review audits. The time of the ban is determined [by an algorithm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190562/). A ban can also be set manually by a moderator if your review history is problematic. You'll be alerted to when the ban will be lifted when you attempt to use the review queue(s) where you have a review ban.

- [The time of automatic review bans should be increased with every new ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/174118/the-time-of-automatic-review-bans-should-be-increased-with-every-new-ban)

Comment: Where can I find this written in the help section? "but usually the first suspension will last 7 days, the second 30 days, and the third 365 days"

Comment: Do you know why an exponential increment of duration was chosen?

Comment: @Sam: If I recall, there was a problematic user who would get suspended for 7 days, then come back and continue his nonsense until suspended for another 7 days. After a couple of cycles of this the idea of increasing the suspension each time was put forth. I've not yet found a meta post talking about this, but it may just have been something that the Moderators discussed among themselves. As far as I know it's not an _official_ policy. A Moderator would really need to answer this.

Comment: Seems rather logical though. If you haven't learned your lesson after a week, a month seems like logical next step.

Comment: @AlE.: of course I believe it's really effective, but also not very diplomatic. One thing is extending the duration of the suspension. Another is doing it an exponential way. It was possible a linear increment: 7, 14, 28 days, 56 and so on.. Usually, the more something is drastic, the more easily it solves problems for who own the power, but using *drastic* punishment also is often less respectful of people's feelings. The middle of the road is often the best solution in my experience.

Comment: 7/30/365 is the progression as prescribed by the interface itself for dealing with a user who is a repeat offender, which thus basically means it is what we suggest for moderators ourselves. Originally it was 7/30/120-or-deletion, but since we're no longer really in the punitive deletion methodology, we switched to 365 days.

Comment: @Sam I'm not particularly concerned about making sure that someone who has made multiple repeat *significant* destructive activities deserves to be coddled and should be walking away happy.  They've proven that they are entirely unwilling or unable to be a productive member of the community and we don't want them here, let alone being happy here, because they have demonstrated that their existence is *greatly* harming those around them.  28 days is highly unlikely to turn such a destructive user into a good one.  After a year, perhaps, and if not, their harm to the site is at least low.

Comment: The help section could do with more info on escalating and appealing bans too. A section on shogging would be helpful too.