# Review ban history sorting doesn't really make sense

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, review-suspension

On `/admin/review/bans/historical`, I can see a [recently-added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298154/215468) list of who's been banned from review historically. It's presented 50 users at a time, paginated and sorted by ban count descending.

The header on that table allows me to change the sort, but it only sorts the presented data - I can sort by ban count ascending... but only on the 50 users it's showing me. Likewise with sorting by username. It's not useful at best, and misleading at worst.

This may be more useful on small sites with fewer than 50 banned reviewers, but in that case it's not hard to just scan the table or search for the username you're looking for.

It'd probably be easiest to disable sorting on that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting is now removed from these tables in the [new mod ux for review suspensions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356377/feature-preview-new-review-suspensions-mod-ux), due to the exact points that you made.

There is now filtering available on that page which allows for searching by User ID or profile URL.

---

> useless table sort
> removed in new interface
> try filter instead