# "Stack Moderators is invite only" announcements

Tags: support, moderators

I'm a moderator on [Arts & Crafts](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/).

Since the site has relatively little activity, most of the messages I get are 'announcements': apparent invitations to participate or (re)view new or updated policies or features.

Whenever I click on one of those titles, I'm shown a page with these messages:

[image: Stack Moderators is invite only. Contact the Team owner to gain access. Welcome! Stack Overflow for Teams makes it easy to search and find answers in a private and secure environment. Stack Moderators is a private knowledge base powered by Stack Overflow for Teams. Have a question? Contact your admin.]
<sup>(Screenshot taken with Dark Reader plugin)</sup>

My questions:

- If at all, how can I get access to these messages?
- If I can't access those unless I have a certain elevated status, how can I turn these notifications off?
- Who is the "Team owner", and who is 'my admin'?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Moderators have their own [Team](https://stackoverflow.com/teams) on Stack Overflow for private questions and answers, or, as you discovered, for the company to let them preview new or updated features and policies, like this one: [New Review Suspensions Mod UX](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356377/295232).

To get access, just ping one of the Community Managers in the [Teachers' Lounge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/teachers-lounge), the chatroom for moderators. They are the Team owners that page is talking about. All this *should* be somewhere in the on-boarding procedure.

Comment: *All this should be somewhere in the on-boarding procedure.* ... In a Q/A on the private Team ...