# Incorrect review suspension canned template for Triage's "Needs community edit"

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, review-suspension

The [new](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356377) canned review suspension message for "Needs community edit" is incorrect.

The current text implies that the user chose the "*Flag*" option, when in actual fact this template is supposed to be used when the user chose the "*Needs community edit*" option (incorrectly) in Triage.

[image]

Current text:

> You chose the *Flag* action for questions that should be closed...

Suggested fix:

> You should choose the *Flag* option for questions that should be closed...

or

> You should choose the "*Needs author edit*" action for questions that should be closed...