# Cannot submit review suspension message because of template tokens

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, review-suspension

I just [suspended a user from review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356377/295232) and used the "Approved spam post" template. I wanted to modify it, because I actually wanted to list another approved post which was clearly Not An Answer as well. When I tried to submit the message, I got the message

> The following template tokens are present and must be replaced: {review-tasks-links}

but that was already in the template, and rightfully so, I guess. Switching to Markdown mode didn't help. In the end, I generated the links myself, so that's a workaround, but it would be better if the intended functionality were restored.

[image: screenshot of message editor with error message]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now fixed

> regressions not fun.
> review suspension message
> generation good

Comment: Hmm ... I don't have a sock with enough reputation to test (you can only suspend users with access to the review queues). Thanks for fixing it, I trust it works now and otherwise I'll report back.

Comment: Ah, I see the fix is that it now properly expands into a list of review tasks immediately after selecting the template. I thought it would do that on submitting, just like the `{optionalSuspensionAutoMessage}` in moderator messages.

Comment: No, it expands it in the draft, giving you a chance to change it before submitting