# Unable to translate "Enter Review Task URL" on review suspension page

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, localization, review-suspension

There's no available source to translate "Enter Review Task URL" placeholder on review suspension page:

> [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to translate it now. Thanks for the report!

Comment: Thanks. Will wait for the next build to check. Current one is 2023.5.30.43465.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ It should be up already, barring no unexpected failures in the string extraction process.

Comment: It can't be ready, since I just translated the string ) One more thing here: I see there is much complicated interface for review queue ban, but I'm pretty sure it almost never used on ruSO. Do you know the history about that tool?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Ahh I see, I thought you meant "will wait for the next build to check Traducir" for some reason. :) As for the tool itself, the current UI was part of the work done on review queues back in 2020: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356377/new-review-suspensions-mod-ux

Comment: Hi, Adam. This is not a bug, so I'm not sure is it eligible to escalate to the staff according [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388089/339911), but please take a look on [that post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/389638/339911) obviously related to the current one. Thanks in advance.