# Split translatable strings related to review suspension tool

Tags: feature-request, status-review, moderator-tools, localization, review-suspension

There're many string related to [review suspension tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356377/new-review-suspensions-mod-ux) that contain exact substrings. E.g:

> [Being suspended can be a frustrating experience, but correct reviews help us maintain quality content on the site.](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=Being%20suspended%20can%20be%20a%20frustrating%20experience%2C%20but%20correct%20reviews%20help%20us%20maintain%20quality%20content%20on%20the%20site.)

> [In the meantime, you can refer to the help center for more information and revisit your recent reviews.](https://ru.traducir.win/filters?sourceRegex=In%20the%20meantime%2C%20you%20can%20refer%20to%20the)

I can't talk for all languages used on SE network, but I hope in all of them such sentences can be used and hence translated separately.

Could we please extract these sentences from the big ones to reduce translators' work to make translations more consistent and easy?

It's good to hold such independent strings separately in general case for translation purposes.

Comment: String composition for translations always runs the risk of the resulting paragraph not making a ton of sense, but I think in this case it's reasonable to split those out.

Comment: @AdamLear In my experience I much often faced with the situations when short phrases or words (like `from`, `to`) must include context before translation. Since I don't know where else it can be used. The very big problem with translations on SE is using string concatenations instead of full sentences. Good example [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305001/339911). BTW since flag history page could be considered as a part of mod tools, it's good candidate to make an internal ticket according to the [current priorities](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/388089/339911).